# How to fetch and show specific user multiple data from multiple arrays in one array?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing chat API in CodeIgniter. Here are my controller and model

```
//show message controller
public function to_user()
{
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    $userto = $data->{'userto'};
    $data=$this->um->to_user($userto);
    echo json_encode($data);
}

//show message model
 function to_user($userto)
 { 
      $this->db->select('message,from_user_email,reg_name,pic_url');
        $this->db->from('t_chat_msg');
        $this->db->where('to_user_email', $userto);
        $this->db->join('registration','t_chat_msg.from_user_email=registration.email','inner');
        $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();
        
        return $query; 
 }
```

When I hit in postman to get result using the parameter.

```
 {
"userto":"nomi_malik01@yahoo.com"
 }
 
 Result:

 [
 {
 "message": "Hi.",
 "from_user_email": "tapy@live.com",
 "reg_name": "Tapy",
 "pic_url": "https://www.develooped.com/qrcode/images/avatar.png"
  },
 {
  "message": "Hello!Testing.",
  "from_user_email": "tapy@live.com",
  "reg_name": "Tapy",
  "pic_url": "https://www.develooped.com/qrcode/images/avatar.png"
 },
 {
  "message": "hi,again",
  "from_user_email": "tapy@live.com",
  "reg_name": "Tapy",
  "pic_url": "https://www.develooped.com/qrcode/images/avatar.png"
  }
]
```

As you can notice email: nomi_malik01@yahoo.com has received a lot of messages from email: tapy@live.com but they are shown in different arrays but I want to show them in a single array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change in your controller**

```
public function to_user()
{
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
  $userto = $data->{'userto'};
  $data=$this->um->to_user($userto);
  foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
        $new_arr[$val['from_user_email']]['from_user_email']=$val['from_user_email'];
        $new_arr[$val['from_user_email']]['reg_name']=$val['reg_name'];
        $new_arr[$val['from_user_email']]['pic_url']=$val['pic_url'];
        $new_arr[$val['from_user_email']]['message'][]=$val['message'];
    }
  //set page header
  $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($new_arr));
}
```

**The output of results**

```
//when sender email is same
{
    "tapy@live.com": {
        "from_user_email": "tapy@live.com",
        "reg_name": "Tapy",
        "pic_url": "https://www.develooped.com/qrcode/images/avatar.png",
        "message": [
            "Hi.",
            "Hello!Testing.",
            "hi,again"
        ]
    }
}

//when sender email is diff.

{
    "tapy@live1.com": {
        "from_user_email": "tapy@live1.com",
        "reg_name": "Tapy",
        "pic_url": "https://www.develooped.com/qrcode/images/avatar.png",
        "message": [
            "Hi."
        ]
    },
    "tapy@live.com": {
        "from_user_email": "tapy@live.com",
        "reg_name": "Tapy",
        "pic_url": "https://www.develooped.com/qrcode/images/avatar.png",
        "message": [
            "Hello!Testing.",
            "hi,again"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: @KundanParsad can't we use other way to display data?Right now we have used [messages][]..  And this empty array is not showing data in my app.

Comment: are you using PhoneGap build for app..?

Comment: i am doing in ionic2

Comment: I am getting this error. Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'.

Comment: Here is my messages.ts method:    recieve(){
    NativeStorage.getItem('user').then(data => {
         console.log(data);
         this.myemail = data.email;

 var link ="https://www.develooped.com/qrcode/index.php/Customer_Controller/to_user";
 var data_string = JSON.stringify({userto:this.myemail});
  this.http.post(link,data_string)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.response = data.json();
            console.log(this.response.messages);

          }, error => {
              console.log("Oooops!");
          });

           }).catch(err => console.log);
      }

Comment: and its my messages.html page:<ion-list>
<ion-card *ngFor = "let user of response" (click)="messagedetail(user.message,user.from_user_email)" >

  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <img  src="{{user.pic_url}}">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>{{user.reg_name}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-card>

</ion-list>

Comment: try to change from `this.response = data.json();` to `this.response = data;` if not working plz give me output of `console.log(data)`

Comment: Still not showing messages. This is the output of response: Response {_body: "{"tapy@live.com":{"from_user_email":"tapy@live.com…ing","I am eating","I am eating","I am eating"]}}", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers…}

url:"https://www.develooped.com/qrcode/index.php/Customer_Controller/to_user"
_body:"{"tapy@live.com":{"from_user_email":"tapy@live.com","reg_name":"Tapy","pic_url":"https:\/\/www.develooped.com\/qrcode\/images\/avatar.png","message":["Hi.","Hello!Testing.","hi,again","I am going","I am coming","I am eating","I am eating","I am eating"]}}"

Comment: is username display here `<h2>{{user.reg_name}}</h2>`

Comment: then use this inside of `<ion-card>` tag  `<div *ngFor = "let msg of user">
   <span>{{msg}}</span>
  </div>`

Comment: let me test this.

Comment: still same errors.  The output we generated is not accepted by  ionic.